# objects in a class, number/array or objects

Tags: c++, class

Maybe I am way-off but I'm trying to self teach c++ object and classes idea, and building very small game.
In that game I will have a big object(class) that will own the board
I want this object to create NUMBER or PlayerClass objects that each will be an object in that board object, I don't know how many will be (players)
I was wondering can i have array of objects?
I have written this code to show what I was looking for:

```
class PlayerClass{
public:
...
private:
    int myLocation[2];
    bool isPlayer=false;
};


class game{
public:
    void MakePlayers(int numberOfPlayers){
        PlayerClass players[numberOfPlayers];
        playerObject=players;
        Number=numberOfPlayers;
    }
private:
    PlayerClass *playerObject
    int Number;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I commend your initiative in trying to teach yourself C++. It's not the easiest language to learn, but it is very powerful once you understand it.

First comment: You want to have more than one `PlayerClass` object. One way to achieve that would be to have a `PlayerClass*` member variable that points to a dynamically-allocated array of players, which seems to be what you're going for. But that entails a lot of manual memory management, which is difficult to get right even if you're experienced with the language. I'd suggest using a `std::vector` instead (make sure to `#include <vector>`):

```
class game
{
   // ...
private:
   std::vector<PlayerClass> m_players; // instead of PlayerClass*
   // no more need for int Number
};
```

Then your constructor can initialize it like so:

```
void MakePlayers(int numberOfPlayers)
    : m_players(numberOfPlayers)
{
}
// if you're being rigorous, you'll want to either change numberOfPlayers to
// an unsigned type or ensure it is nonnegative before using it
```

`vector` supports the `[]` operator with the same semantics as a regular array, so you can still access individual players as (e.g.) `m_players[3]`. Further, a `vector` knows how many elements it contains (`size()` member function), so there is no longer any need to keep track of the number of players separately.

Good luck!

Update: One of your comments says you're coming to C++ from C, so maybe manual memory management isn't so unfamiliar for you after all ;). Still, as Stephane Rolland points out, it's almost never necessary in modern C++ thanks to the helpful classes in the standard library. If you find yourself wanting to do it out of habit, make sure to consider first whether it's really necessary.

Comment: Maybe you state more clearly that avoiding the use of pointers (when possible and it's often possible) is good pratice in modern c++.

Comment: ok, first its a big jump for me, to see this vector, i will be reading about it now
say, where should i put the "std::vector<PlayerClass> m_players;"?
secend, how i get the size()?should it be "m_players.size()"
thx soo much!!!

Comment: @JohnnyF my suggestion was to put the declaration of `m_players` in place of the `PlayerClass *playerObject` you have now (the `m_` prefix is optional; it's just a convention some people use for member variables). Yes, `m_players.size()` would be the way to get the number of players after the fact.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for that:

```
class game {
    std::vector<PlayerClass> players_;

  public:
    game (std::size_t NumPlayers) : players_ (NumPlayers) {}
}
```

Comment: hi, first of all thx for your time,
but as someone who just came from c
i have noo ideaaa what is writen there or what it does...

Comment: learn `std::vector`, it's the c++ tool to use for arrays. It's similar, but easier and cleaner to use than c-style arrays.

Comment: @JohnnyF `but as someone who just came from c i have noo ideaaa what is writen there or what it does`  Which means that no matter how much C you know, C++ is a different language.  What you see there is elementary C++.  Also, since you come from 'C', I recommend `Accelerated C++` so that you get a real introduction to C++, and not the "traditional" approach of starting with 'C' coding practices.

Comment: @JohnyF std::size_t is a type for containers length, I think it's equivalent to unsigned long, std::vector is a template, which is instanciated on the type PlayerClass, it creates at compile time a type std::vector<PlayerClass> that is the standard way to contain several objects of type PlayerClass. There exists other container templates.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but you have error in your function MakePlayers, it should be

```
void MakePlayers(int numberOfPlayers){

        playerObject= new (PlayerClass*)[numberOfPlayers];
        Number = numberOfPlayers;

        for (int i = 0; i++; i < numberOfPlayers)
        {
            playerObject[i] = new PlayerClass();
        }
    }
```

Also, you need free playerObject in the class destructor to avoid memory leak. Another advice, please understand what is pointer first.